# Getting table structure with div with grouped divs

Tags: html, css

I want a tabular data which is in groups.
Wanted all cells of equal width. Please refer code below.

```css
  .details {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
  }
  .row {
      display: table-row;
  }
  .cell1, .cell2, .cell3 {
       width: 100%;
       display: table-cell;
       border: 1px solid gray;

  }
  .groups {
       border: 1px solid red;
  }

  .group-name {
       font-weight: bold;
  }
```

```html
    <div class="details">
         <div class="groups">
              <div class="group-name">
                         one
              </div>
              <div class="list">
                 <div class="row">
                       <div class="cell1">
                            cell1
                       </div>
                       <div class="cell2">
                            cell2
                       </div>
                       <div class="cell3">
                            cell3
                       </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                       <div class="cell1">
                            cell1
                       </div>
                       <div class="cell2">
                            cell2
                       </div>
                       <div class="cell3">
                            cell3
                       </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
         </div>
         <div class="groups">
              <div class="group-name">
                         two
              </div>
              <div class="list">
                 <div class="row">
                       <div class="cell1">
                            cell1
                       </div>
                       <div class="cell2">
                            cell2 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                       </div>
                       <div class="cell3">
                            cell3
                       </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                       <div class="cell1">
                            cell1 
                       </div>
                       <div class="cell2">
                            cell2 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                       </div>
                       <div class="cell3">
                            cell3 some big Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                       </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **flex** for equal size.

```css
 .details {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
  }
  .row {
      display: table-row;
      display:flex;
  }
  .cell1{
       width: 30%;
       display: table-cell;
       border: 1px solid gray;
      flex: 1;
  
  padding: 1em;


  }
 .cell2 {
       width: 30%;
       display: table-cell;
       border: 1px solid gray;
        flex: 1; 
  
  padding: 1em;
 

  }
 .cell3 {
       width: 30%;
       display: table-cell;
       border: 1px solid gray;
       flex: 1; 
        padding: 1em;


  }
  .groups {
       border: 1px solid red;
  }

  .group-name {
       font-weight: bold;
  }
```

```html
<div class="details">
         <div class="groups">
              <div class="group-name">
                         one
              </div>
              <div class="list">
                 <div class="row">
                       <div class="cell1">
                            cell1
                       </div>
                       <div class="cell2">
                            cell2
                       </div>
                       <div class="cell3">
                            cell3
                       </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                       <div class="cell1">
                            cell1
                       </div>
                       <div class="cell2">
                            cell2
                       </div>
                       <div class="cell3">
                            cell3
                       </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
         </div>
         <div class="groups">
              <div class="group-name">
                         two
              </div>
              <div class="list">
                 <div class="row">
                       <div class="cell1">
                            cell1
                       </div>
                       <div class="cell2">
                            cell2 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                       </div>
                       <div class="cell3">
                            cell3
                       </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                       <div class="cell1">
                            cell1 
                       </div>
                       <div class="cell2">
                            cell2 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                       </div>
                       <div class="cell3">
                            cell3 some big Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                       </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Just want another help if you can. I want one of the column to be fixed irrespective of data exists or not. As of now it is distorting.

Comment: Sorry.Can you explain me clearly. The columns are fixed only.

Comment: I wanted fixed width for a particular column. I achieved it with min-width and max-width though. Thanks for all the help.